# Change base URL for email activation link?

Tags: craft3, plugins, users, emails, navigation

I am using Craft as a headless CMS and have set base Url/siteUrl to the url of my React/Gatsby site.

I needed to do this as my navigation plugin, [Navie](https://github.com/dutchheight/craft-navie), appends it by default.

But now when users registers, they are sent an activation email with the Gatsby url.

How can I change this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Twig `replace` filter in the email template to replace the URL with whatever you like. (I'm using this method myself because we have a similar problem on multi-site installs). To do this you'll need to be using custom templates for all system emails: `Settings > Email > HTML Email Template`

I'd set that to something like `emails/index`, which could then be like this, routing out to separate template files depending on the `emailKey`:

```
{# Craft has four predefined email keys:

    account_activation
    verify_new_email
    forgot_password
    test_email

... route to them here, or fallback to default
#}

{% include [
    'emails/' ~ emailKey ?? null,
    'emails/default'
] %}
```

Then `emails/account_activation.twig` could be something like this using the replace filter on the `link` variable:

```
{% extends 'emails/_emailLayout' %}

{% set lockscreenText = 'Activate your account' %}

{%- set heading -%}
    Hi {{ user.friendlyName ?? 'there' }},
{%- endset -%}

{% block content %}
    <p>Your account is now set up and ready to use, with your email address as your username.</p>
    <p>To activate your account, click the following link:</p>
{% endblock %}

{% if link is not defined %}
    {% set link = 'http://local.test' %}
{% endif %}
{% set buttonLink = link|replace('https://old.com/actions','https://new.com/actions') %}
{% set buttonText = 'Activate your account' %}
```

...while `emails/_emailLayout` would have all the complicated mess of HTML that cross-client email requires.